# closure of polynomials in weak topoloy and weak* topology of $L^\infty(0,1)$.

Tags: functional-analysis, lebesgue-integral, dual-spaces

> closure of polynomials in weak topoloy and weak* topology of $L^\infty(0,1)$?

I know $(L^1)'=L^\infty$, and the dual of $L^\infty$ is just Radon measures. How to find the  closure of polynomials in weak topoloy and weak* topology of $L^\infty(0,1)$? I just know the basic definition in topology.

Comment: Actually, the dual of $L^\infty$ is not the space of finite measures, but the space of charges (which are only finitely additive). Besides, referring to Radon measures seems a bit strange in this context, as all finite Borel measures on $(0,1)$ are Radon.

Comment: Since the set $P$ of polynomials is convex, its weak closure is  the same as the norm closure. Then Weierstraß's approximation theorem gives the answer. For the weak$^*$ topology show that every $f\in L^1(0,1)$ with $\int f(x)p(x)dx=0$ for all polynomials $p$ is zero. 

If you *just know the basic definitions in topology* (and no functional analysis like Hahn-Banach and its consequences), this exercise is probably very hard.

Comment: @Jochen Thank you. I have got the weak closure as you suggested. What about the weak star closure? What is it? I know functional analysis.

Comment: The weak$^*$ topology on $L^\infty$ is the coarsest topology making all maps $L^\infty\to \mathbb K$, $g\mapsto \int f(x)g(x)dx$ for $f\in L^1$
 continuous. The closure of the polynomials in this topology is all of $L^\infty$.

Comment: @Jochen How to find it ?  Can you give some more hints/

Comment: The dual of $L^\infty$ with the weak$^*$-topology is $L^1$ (i.e., every wea$^*$-ontinuous linear functional is of the form $g\mapsto \int f(x)g(x)dx$ for some $f\in L^1$). Use Hahn-Banach.